# SQL Server database field to handle korean and chinese characters

Tags: sql-server, database, internationalization, cjk

Is it possible to have a field in SQL Server that can store Chinese, Korean and European characters?  My Chinese characters just become `?????`

The datatype is `NVARCHAR` as well.

Comment: Do you need to store English as well?

Comment: Hi ardman - Yes english as well

Answer (score 67):

`NVARCHAR` is the proper type for this - it stores everything in a 2-byte Unicode.

What you need to pay attention to is when working with `NVARCHAR` fields in SQL Server Management Studio - you absolutely **must** use the `N'....'` prefix in that case!

If you use this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(NVarcharColumn)
    VALUES('Some Chinese text here')
```

then SSMS will **temporarily convert** the string literal you specify into `VARCHAR` (non-Unicode!) and thus you'll loose any Unicode-encoded characters.

However, if you use:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(NVarcharColumn)
    VALUES(N'Some Chinese text here')
```

(note the **N** prefix before the string literal!) then SSMS will handle everything as Unicode all the time, and your Chinese or Korean (or other) special characters should be preserved.

Comment: thanks for this, it doesn't seem to work though.. I have a feeling i'm missing some setting somewhere?

Comment: @Alessandro: are you trying to deal with data in SSMS, or from a client application? Also: which collation do you use on your server and on your database??

Comment: Via a coldfusion based web application.. Although i tried that script directly in SSMS

SERVER COLLATION: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
DB COLLATION : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: This fixed my issue! :D

Comment: I had set my column type to varchar and it displayed the char as ?, when i changed this to nvarchar it successfully stored Chinese, Japanese, and Korean characters. I did confirm that my database Collation was already set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score 0):

Need to change the datatype of column to Nvarchar

```
insert into [dbo].[tablename] (columnname)values(N'日本')
```