# Trying to insert a select statement with Chinese column in Query field in a Data Set table, the chinese language fileds are showing as?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have [Data Set] table with columns called `Id` and `IncrementalQuery`.

In the `IncrementalQuery` column, I am inserting a select statement like:

```
Select CAST([省] as NVARCHAR(max)) as [Receive_Area(CN)], CAST([市] as DC_Area(CN) from TableName
```

But when I checked the `[Data Set]` table, I see that the `IncrementalQuery` column has a value like:

```
Select CAST([?] as NVARCHAR(max)) as [Receive_Area(CN)], CAST([?] as DC_Area(CN) from TableName
```

Could you please help me how to show this Chinese values instead of a question Mark '?'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server database field to handle korean and chinese characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736656/sql-server-database-field-to-handle-korean-and-chinese-characters)

Comment: The incrementalquery column datatype is nvarchar(max) in my dataset table.
While inserting i tried N''省'' and '省' but still they are showing as ?

Comment: The link didnt help me

Comment: @user15488631 - how are you "checking the [Data Set]"?  Are you just running a SELECT statement in SQL Server Mgmt Studio?  If so, it might be worth checking that your grid results are displaying in a unicode-capable font.  (Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colours -> Show Settings for "Grid Results".  Double-check that the font used there is one that can show the relevant characters ....... otherwise, the correct data might be stored in the database, but the font just shows "?" because it can't show the Chinese characters)

Comment: i tried changing to Gridresults and ran the insert statment  but no luck. The gidresults doesnt show chinese chanracters over there.

Comment: @user15488631 - it may also come down to how you're actually doing the insert.  For example, I tested a simple insert into a column - using INSERT INTO <column> VALUES ('SELECT [省]');  and then INSERT INTO <column> VALUES (N'SELECT [省]');  When I then select from the table, the first value I inserted has ?, the second shows the expected character.  So, it may be that the string value you are insert into your [Data Set] table is not inherently unicode, so then SQL interprets it in its default fashion, which results in the Chinese character being droppped

Comment: @user15488631, there's a question here that has some good descriptions of SQL's behaviour regarding unicode / non-unicode strings  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155859/why-do-we-need-to-put-n-before-strings-in-microsoft-sql-server, but you'd likely be able to find plenty of different references about it with an online search, that would suit your particular situation (as I say, you don't specify how the actual insert is occurring)

Comment: Hi Craig thanks for the help i fallowed your instructions it worked 
INSERT INTO <column> VALUES (N'SELECT [省]')
Thank you for your help,

Comment: @user15488631 - Good news!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a straight SQL INSERT that you're running, then I suspect the statement will need to be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Data Set] (Id,IncrementalQuery)
VALUES (1, N'Select CAST([省] as NVARCHAR(max)) as [Receive_Area(CN)] ,CAST([市] as DC_Area(CN) from TableName');
```

(Don't know whether your Id column is auto-incrementing or not - obviously, if it is, then it doesn't need to be included in the column list, or given a value)

The "N" prefix on the string explicitly tells SQL to treat the string as unicode