Collation for cyrillic, chinese and sweden symbols in MsSql server
I have a table in whicn one column need to be able to store a lot of different characters - cyrillic, chinese, swedish etc. Currently there is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation and it is not ideal. Microsoft recomends for swedish Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS. For chinese there is still option Latin1_General_CI_AI. But what collation can be used to display all of different characters? And is it bad decision to change collation for one column? Read info about not changing because of getting "cannot resolve collation conflict" errors.

So are you using a varchar and then different collations in the 2 columns/databases? Why not ensure you use nvarchar in both locations and ensure that are using the same collation? Then your characters are stored using UCS-2/UTF-16 (depending if your collation uses supplementary characters or not). There isn't going to be an appropriate collation for storage of Cyrillic, Chinese, and Swedish characters (in a varchar) unless you use a UTF-8 collation, and that has its own caveats.

That column is in NVARCHAR and with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation as it is default for this DB. And that column was used to store cyrillic data. But now it needs to store also chinese, swedish and others characters. And my question is - do I need another collation? As I did not find info about if this collation (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) can properly display swedish characters. For chinese as I understand it is good enough

As I mentioned, nvarchar is UCS-2/UTF-16 (depending if your collation uses supplementary characters or not); it uses 2(+) bytes to store characters. It has no issues storing characters that appear outside of the code page of the collation. I assume you've tested storing characters of many different alphabets, and it's not working and why you're here. Can you demonstrate why the code you have isnt' working? Can you create a [mre] showing (presumably) a loss of characters?

Found here useful info after your comments about nvarchar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736656/sql-server-database-field-to-handle-korean-and-chinese-characters. Thanks a lot

So are you saying that the real problem was that you were using varchar literals, not nvarchar literals?

Yes, will be looking how application insert works for starters. Tried adding new characters through application. Thought that problem was collation
